# TFS2010 - merge not picking up differences where newer file changes in target

Tags: tfs, merge

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've been looking for a while and can't find an answer to this question.

We have "Main" and "Dev" branches - "Main" was the first, and then we branched "Main" (parent) to "Dev" (child).  Development changes were made in "Dev", but now we want to in effect "rollback" those changes in "Dev" to what is in "Main", which is older.  But when I run a merge from "Main" to "Dev", for files that exist in both branches, it does not notice any of those newer changes in "Dev" as differences at all.  What I'm expecting is that merge will notice every file that has a difference, whether or not that difference is due to a newer change made in the target branch.  Is this an unrealistic expectation?

I've gotten to the point where I believe my only recourse is to use a different "diff" tool to tell me the differences in each file between "Main" and "Dev", and then go file by file and force a merge from the older "Main" file to the newer "Dev" file - to overlay what's in "Dev".

Is there a way to get the standard TFS Merge to do what I want - and show me the differences in each file between "Main" and "Dev", and for each one, pop up the conflict dialog and allow me to choose how to merge??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This looks pretty similar to what you describe but you'll need to use the command line tf.exe:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092863/tfs-overwrite-a-branch-with-another

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll back dev to the same state as main just delete Dev and create a new branch for Dev.

If you want to keep what is in Dev then create a new branch for Dev from main.

To get a diff you need to do a merge between Dev and main as the change are in Dev.

There is also a built in diff to in TFS for this. On source explorer you should see a diff icon at the top of the screen.